# SQL query conditioned by another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Beginner with SQL in need of help here is the problem. Can be SQL stmt for any DB i am testing on postgresql.
I have the following issue for 2 SQL tables:

**Table number 1**

```
 .....................  
|Boy Name| Girl Name |  
|--------------------|  
|Michael |  Anne     |  
|Michael |  Misty    |  
|Michael |  Simone   |  
|Michael |  Diane    |  
|Michael |  Ariel    |  
|Jack    |  Misty    |  
|Jack    |  Simone   |  
|Jack    |  Anne     |  
|Sam     |  Simone   |  
|Sam     |  Misty    |  
|Sam     |  Anne     |  
|Sam     |  Mini     |  
|Sam     |  Valery   |   
----------------------
```

**Table number 2**

```
..................................
|Boy Name | Anne | Misty | Simone|
|--------------------------------|
|Michael  |  yes | no    |  no   | 
|Jack     |  yes | yes   |  yes  | 
|Sam      |  no  | no    |  yes  | 
..................................
```

(IDK is like a question: does a girl like a specific boy. Can be yes, no or nothing).

**Desired result**

A table where the query returns 2 columns:
- a row for every "no" a boy gets from a girl via table number 2.

```
.....................
|Boy Name| Girl Name |
|--------------------|
|Michael |  Misty    |
|Michael |  Simone   |
|Sam     |  Misty    |
|Sam     |  Anne     |
----------------------
```

You can think of the result as a new row a with a column for the boy's name and another one with the name of the girl that had "no" in table number 2 .

Comment: Do you want to say that with every new girl, you'll add new column in Table2? Is that final design or just your proposed one? Regardless to your answer, people here do not really like such questions where you just ask do not provide something to prove that you tried to do that by yourself

Comment: Hello @DmitrijKultasev, regarding topic about new column for every girl question short answer would be no, table 2 has just some random picked girls. The other thing, i am kinda new around and just started out with SQL, thanks for the heads up, but at this point idk how to start.

Comment: You can start learning SQL here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would suggest different table design:

```
CREATE TABLE person
(
 id INT PRIMARY KEY,
 person_name VARCHAR(200),
 sex CHAR(1)
);
-- possible record: 1, 'John', 'M'; 2, 'Mary', 'F';

CREATE TABLE person_symphaty
(
 person_id INT, -- FK to person table
 symphaty_person_id INT -- FK to person table
);
-- you will store here if the person likes another one. 1 point here is that you can store that person doesn't like somebody, then you need some flag, for example is_symphaty INT (then 1 will mean likes, 0 will mean dislike)
```

then the query itself

```
    SELECT pm.name AS male_name, pf.name AS female_name
    FROM person pm
    CROSS JOIN person pf
    WHERE pm.sex = 'M' AND pf.sex = 'F'
NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM person_symphaty ps WHERE ps.person_id = pm.id AND ps.symphaty_person_id = pf.id
    )
```

There could be mistakes as I didn't test these queries at all.

Comment: thank you for the design update. I will study this approach tonight and get back to you.